# how to disable test programs in cross-compiling glib

Tags: cross-compilation, glib

I've the following errors when trying to cross-compile glib, with the following configuration parameters:

./configure --prefix=$HOME --host=arm-hisiv400-linux

```
checking for growing stack pointer... configure: error: in `/home/aa/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/glib-2.50.0':
configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling
See `config.log' for more details
```

Is there a way to disable these tests so that my cross-compile process can get through?

Comment: I'm guessing `./configure --help` might help.

Comment: No it doesn't as it doesn't have disable-test listed as one of the option.

Answer (score 3):

The standard practice in this type of situation is to use an [Autoconf site default file](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Site-Defaults.html) containing the appropriate values for the tests that `configure` wants to run.

In this particular case, [`configure`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/configure.ac#n614) is trying to determine in which direction the stack grows:

```
    volatile int *a = 0, *b = 0;
    void f (int i) { volatile int x = 5; if (i == 0) b = &x; else f (i - 1); }
    int main () { volatile int y = 7; a = &y; f (100); return b > a ? 0 : 1; }
```

So you'd cross-compile that code, run it on your target platform, and examine its exit code (`echo $?`). Create a site default file for your target architecture, for example `config.arm-hisiv400-linux`, and add a line with

```
glib_cv_stack_grows=yes
```

(if the exit code above was 0), or

```
glib_cv_stack_grows=no
```

(if the exit code was 1).

Then run `configure` with `CONFIG_SITE` pointing to the full path of the site default file you just created:

```
CONFIG_SITE=/path/to/config.arm-hisiv400-linux ./configure --prefix=$HOME --host=arm-hisiv400-linux
```

`configure` should use the value from the site default file, skipping the test for the stack. It will probably fail on the next test which needs to run a program compiled for the target, but you can fix that in the same way, adding more entries to the site default file (as long as `configure.ac` uses `AC_CACHE_VAL` around `AC_TRY_RUN`).